# Powershell: get all .yaml files, execute commands on those yaml files, then rename them

Tags: python, powershell

I would like to make a Powershell script to do the following (typed up in Python to demonstrate):

```py
CommandTemplate = "toPDF main.tex xyz"                  # a command template
ListOfFiles = glob.glob("*.yaml")                       # get all yaml files in cwd
for file in ListOfFiles:                                # iterate thry
    os.system(CommandTemplate.replace("xyz", file))      # call command, will make a main.pdf. Maybe want to wrap this in brackets?
    os.rename("main.pdf", file.replace(".yaml", ".pdf")) # rename main.pdf to match yaml
```

I have no idea where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Update the directory path and text to replace as per your requirement.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "d:\Test" -Name *.yaml

foreach($file in $files)
{
 ((Get-Content -path "d:\test\$file") -replace 'abc','def') | Set-Content -Path "D:\test\$file"
 $newName = $file.Split('.')[0]
 Rename-Item -Path d:\test\$file -NewName "$newName.pdf"
}
```

Comment: I don't see where a command is actually executed; can you please explain where I would place the `toPDF main.tex` part of the command?